# Where do the logs go with error_log function?

Tags: php

I recently got already written php project, and I am trying to work on it. I can see that all logs are written to the specific location using `file_put_contents()` function.

But I can see that there's `error_log()` function in one place, without a destination file given. It looks like this:

```
error_log($str);
```

Where can I find logs file in this case?

Comment: Have you read http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-log.php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error log file is set with the error_log directoive in php.ini.

If the directive is not set, the file location is managed by the SAPI error logger, which in case of Apache it is in "Apache" logs directory.

You can find if this directive have a value with phpinfo()